# Handle TextArea auto-height in Flexbox Context

Tags: css, cross-browser, flexbox

I'm aware existing topics are already posted on the subject of auto-height for textarea, using either `this.height = this.scrollHeight` technique, or use a `contenteditable` element.

I chose the contenteditable way, seemed more cleaner to me...
works perfectly when used "as is", but totally fails in flexbox containers.

I tried working out some solution using `max-height` and `min-height` a bit everywhere without success...

The problem is when adding a new line inside the "textarea", the text overflows outside... when i want the textarea to automatically "push" its upper bound (not down!)
Same problem when suppressing a new line, attempts i did didnot update the element's height.

[FULL code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Sharlaan/pen/OmoqxK)

> CSS

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

*:focus { outline: 0; }

.app-title {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tchat-container {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

section {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

article {
  background: #FDD835;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tchat-footer {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

.autoExpand {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;

  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.autoExpand:focus {
  border-color: cornflowerblue;
}

button {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.app-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
}
```

> HTML

```
<header class='app-title'>APP TITLE</header>
<div class='tchat-container'>
  <header>Title</header>
  <section>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
  </section>
  <footer class='tchat-footer'>
    <p contenteditable='true' class='autoExpand' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></p>
    <button>Send</button>
  </footer>
</div>
<footer class='app-footer'>APP FOOTER</footer>
```

a CSS-only solution would be ideal, but i didnot find any way to make Chrome, Firefox and Edge (last versions) happy...

**UPDATE**
i finally found what i missed:
the class `tchat-footer` were missing `flex: 1 0 auto`,
and accessorily a `min-height` for `.autoExpand`.
[FIXED codepen](https://codepen.io/Sharlaan/pen/qmJLYw)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```js
// Applied globally on all textareas with the "autoExpand" class
  const autoExpandingTextAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.autoExpand')

  for (let aeta of autoExpandingTextAreas) {
    aeta.addEventListener('input', event => {
      console.log(
          'height', event.currentTarget.style.height,
          '\nscrollHeight', event.currentTarget.scrollHeight
        )
        // event.currentTarget.style.height = event.currentTarget.scrollHeight + 'px'
    })
  }
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.app-title {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tchat-container {
  --tchat-container-width: 300px;
  --tchat-container-padding: 20px;
  width: var(--tchat-container-width);
  padding: var(--tchat-container-padding);
  padding-right: 0;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: calc(100vh - 188px);
}

section {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

article {
  background: #FDD835;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tchat-footer {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.autoExpand {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 75%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.autoExpand:focus {
  border-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.buttons-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
}

.app-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class='app-title'>APP TITLE</header>
  <div class='tchat-container'>
    <header>Title</header>
    <section>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
      <article>Something very long to test content wrapping and overflow...</article>
    </section>
    <footer class='tchat-footer'>
      <p contenteditable='true' class='autoExpand' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></p>
      <button>Send</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <footer class='app-footer'>APP FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but i actually NOT want text to overflow the typing area.
Instead i wish the textarea to expand its height.

Comment: Works very nicely ! Thanks.
I were battling with tchat-footer flex-grow/shrink/basis...

I always been told to never use display table and the likes for anything else than tabularized data, but for my use-case i have to admit this works like a charm.

Comment: if anyone has an alternative solution using flexbox instead of `display: table`, feel free to complement @Div_P answer.

Comment: EDIT: i just discovered this solution doesnot work on Edge: the whole tchat-footer gets half overflowed from tchat-container.     

on Firefox, the initial cursor inside is weirdly positioned top instead of vertically centered, but goes back to correct position once start typing...    
Here is the [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/Sharlaan/pen/OmoqxK) i used
Note: there are differences between real rendering and codepen's ...